What is this shortened, BSD-3-Clause-like license?
For the first time in my life, I have ran across a license that looks like a popular license, but that I have not been able to recognize or find on Google. I ran into it looking at the license for what I think is an older reference implementation of AES-XTS.
 Copyright (c) 1998-2008, Brian Gladman, Worcester, UK. All rights reserved.
 
 LICENSE TERMS
 
 The redistribution and use of this software (with or without changes)
 is allowed without the payment of fees or royalties provided that:
 
  1. source code distributions include the above copyright notice, this
     list of conditions and the following disclaimer;

  2. binary distributions include the above copyright notice, this list
     of conditions and the following disclaimer in their documentation;

  3. the name of the copyright holder is not used to endorse products
     built using this software without specific written permission.

 DISCLAIMER

 This software is provided 'as is' with no explicit or implied warranties
 in respect of its properties, including, but not limited to, correctness
 and/or fitness for purpose.

This license is extremely similar to a traditional BSD-3-Clause license, except:

The first paragraph clarifies what exactly the license applies to ("this software") more than BSD-3-Clause, has an extra bit about "without the payment of fees or royalties", and stops before saying "the following conditions are met"
Requirement 1 is reworded a bit
Requirement 2 is reworded and made stricter by requiring that binary distributions include the license information in their documentation (whereas BSD-3-Clause allows for it to be in "other materials provided with the distribution")
Requirement 3 is reworded a bit
The disclaimer at the end is given a header and is dramatically shortened and simplified

I've tried searching for a bunch of different permissive licenses, tried to look for anything called "simplified BSD-3-Clause" or "modified BSD-3-Clause", and plugged the full text of the license directly into Google, all without success. The only hint I got is I found one other piece of software that uses a component under the same license, and that component is by the same author: https://github.com/XKCP/XKCP/blob/master/LICENSE
At this point I'm suspecting that this is just a customization of the BSD-3-Clause license that "Brian Gladman" came up with and used for whatever reason, but it sounds so familiar (probably because it's very BSD-like) that I'm wondering if this is actually an established, more-obscure BSD variant in semi-common use. Is this actually an established open-source license, or is this just a one-off thing?

As Brandin pointed out in a since-deleted comment, this licence is known already, and has an SPDX identifier.  In its canonical form, it carries an additional permission to relicence under GPL, but (a) that's been removed in the version you quote, and (b) it's pointless anyway, since content released under fully-permissive licences such as BSD3 may be included in a GPL work anyway.
I don't quite understand why people feel it would be a good idea to "slightly modify" established free licences to suit their whims.  We certainly have some excellent reasons why such "crayon" licences are a bad idea.  But you're right that that's what this is.
